# Can't reach refs of react component

Tags: reactjs

I created canvas element with ref="canvas" property.
When i try to get them in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this.refs);
}
```

There is empty Object.

BUT, then i do

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this);
}
```

I see React element with non-empty 'refs' Object containing my canvas!

How can this happen?

Comment: why do you have arrow functions like that? can you show us more of the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are setting the value of `componentDidMount` to be a function that will evaluate in order to set the result of `componentDidMount`. At the time, `this.refs` isn't populated because the component is firing that function pre-render. However, by just logging `this`, the console will eventually pick up the updated component so you can see `refs` inside of it. Here is how you should structure the component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.refs)
}
```

Does that make sense? You're doing the equivilent of this...

```
class Foo {
  bar = () => {
    console.log('I get called when foo loads to determine the value of bar')
  }
}
```

instead of this

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    console.log('I get called with bar()')
  }
}
```

I'm not able to actually test my code as this syntax is invalid, so I'm not sure how it's working for you...

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, but I can't solve it. Can you explain more detaily ? I have Modal with some ref, and in render after <Modal . ..../> I have code like this ` some ? this.refs.modal.open()` but my refs object is empty